# Upload csv file data on hyperledger fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

How to upload csv file data on hyperledger fabric network to be able to retrieve it and perform some analysis and again want to upload it on network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Node-Red

see tutorial here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/tutorials/nodered-tutorial

There is a `Hyperledger-Composer-out` node that will allow you to take data from a CSV and upload to the blockchain ledger (as seen in the tutorial).

See also https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/integrating/node-red.html